# Log4j2 and InstanceAlreadyExistsException, when creating a Logger

Tags: log4j2, loggerfactory

I moved from log4j to log4j2 and see the following Exception stack, 
when calling:

`private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.mine.pto.ejb_access.MyClass.class);`

The exception is thrown sometimes, when using multiple threads inside the applicaiton.

Any idea what I am doing wrong with the Log4j2?

```
2015-10-13 16:18:48,029 ERROR Could not register mbeans javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1304568236,component=Loggers,name=com.mine.pto.ejb_access
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:513)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.register(Server.java:375)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.registerLoggerConfigs(Server.java:344)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:182)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:143)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:372)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:426)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:442)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:285)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:305)
...
```

Comment: Can you also post your log4j2.xml configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late here, but try to disable JMX using `log4j2.disableJmx` system property and see if that helps. Check here for more info [JMX](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html)

Comment: Thanks for the trick. This workaround works well. So this is the best answer so far, and probably until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1094 is fixed.
Of course, JMX support is disabled but I guess this is acceptable in most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1094 .

If so, the fix is to call `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` before starting any threads.